# Un-Pivot table in Excel 2011 on Mac

Tags: macos, excel, unpivot

On Windows (Excel 2007), there is a way of unpivoting a table by pressing alt + d then p then selecting multiple consolidation ranges then I will create my page fields then finish. This creates a pivot look which appears like the data but double clicking on the grand total provides an unpivoted look at the data.

How can I achieve the same thing using Excel 2011? Alt + D does not seem to work on a Mac… any advice?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this work? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUXJLzqlEPk add the wizard via excel options.

Comment: VBA: http://superuser.com/a/583083/215816

Answer (score 2):

After 2 days of research, I found it. The 3rd answer works:

How to unpivot a table in Mac Excel 2011:

1. Press: Command + Alt + P to bring up the Pivot Table wizard
2. Choose the 3rd option "Consolidate Multiple Ranges"
3. Choose "I will define my page fields"
4. Select the whole table and add it to
   the ranges
5. Click finish (to create the pivot table in a new sheet
   or existing sheet)
6. The pivot table will look like your original
   table at this point
7. Go to the lower-right corner cell, and double
   click it.

Voila, you have your flat unpivoted table.