# Excel - Grouped Semicolon Delimited Values into Individual rows - maintaining the first column

Tags: excel

This is my first post so hoping you geniuses can help.

I have data in an excel table that is currently in this format:

[image: current data format]

As you can see from the above, there is one row per person and all their roles are grouped into one cell in the next column, and are semicolon seperated

What im trying to do is get the data into the following format, where there is a row per role and the name of the person repeats where it needs to:

[image: desired data format]

This is a basic example. My sheet contains 1500 rows and the cell with the roles can have up to 100 or so roles in it

I am using the latest Excel for Mac

Any advice would be much much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Is this a one off task? Do you just want to use Excel?

Comment: ive had to do this a few times now so im happy to use something else that gets the job done so i have it in my arsenal for next time

Comment: Did you look at [Un-Pivot table in Excel 2011 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370001/un-pivot-table-in-excel-2011-on-mac)? If that doesn't work, VBA is always an option.

Answer (score 1):

Use Power Query.

1. Load the data into Power Query with the "From Table" command.
2. select the Role column and split by delimiter. You know which one
3. Select the Name column and use Unpivot > Other columns

Rename the columns and load the query into the grid.

The next time, copy your data into the table from step 1 and hit Refresh All.

**Edit:** Just realised you are using a Mac. Some Power Query functionality is not yet available on the Mac.

Comment: See this un-pivot-table-in-excel-2011-on-mac https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370001/un-pivot-table-in-excel-2011-on-mac?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Power Query is available on the mac, just not with all features available to the Windows version. Google it.